# Job search results dependent on time

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, search

In the job section the search results are very different depending on the time you execute the search. For example, if I execute this search https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=seattle&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles around 5pm EST, I get only 7 results, but I get over 70 if I execute the search at around 1am EST. This is not an isolated event, it is happening every day.

Comment: Did you perform the searches using the same internet connection both times? Results can differ based on IP, due to restrictions in the advertising region of job listings

Comment: Yes, both searches are performed on the same computer using the same internet connection.

Comment: @bosonix can you visit [this](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=whats+my+ip) link in Google at each time and let us know whether the IP addresses are the same? The only way this could happen is if your IP changed between these times to look like it's in a different part of the world. Perhaps a VPN or proxying issue?

Comment: I checked the IP, it is the same on both times, but results are still different. It seems that this happens several times during the day.

Comment: @bosonix thanks, I'm investigating further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked our search logs and HAProxy logs for all searches performed from any IP that you logged into in the past month and the only ones that filter by 'seattle' all had 7 results.

That means that the searches that returned with > 70 results did not hit our servers from your IP at all. I'd suspect an upstream caching issue; if you have one configured then it'd be worthwhile trying to change it and if you don't then it's possible your ISP has a transparent proxy configured.

Let us know if you have any further info and I'll dig deeper!

UPDATE: A bug related to location was raised and fixed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314869/inconsistent-results-between-jobs-and-careers); let us know if that affects the results you're seeing.

Comment: I do not have any cache configured. If the searches with 70 results come from my ISP proxy's cache, then I suppose this means that someone who has the same ISP as me was able to see the full 70 results in the same region as me at some point. But I do not understand what kind of proxy will cache a HTTP response with a session? Maybe you do not have the correct cache headers set?

Comment: @bosonix I completely agree, I'm checking our cache headers - this could be a proxy issue on our side (Careers is proxied through SO)... I'll update once I've poked more. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @bosonix our cache headers are set correctly and your request definitely didn't hit our servers at all. I've triple-checked the code we have for caching results but it only caches for anonymous users anyway. Were you authenticated when you saw the discrepancy? I'm checking to see if our upstream caching is doing something strange here.

Comment: I just did now (3.00 PM EST +/- 1 minute) several requests using the search URL from the question. I am logged in and the results number changed from 77 to 5 between one request and the following.

Comment: @bosonix there are no requests in our load balancer or upstream provider logs to indicate that you hit us at all. There *has* to be something upstream of you that is causing inconsistent behaviour...

Comment: Does it matter that I do the search using stackoverflow.com/jobs or careers.stackoverflow.com? And just for the record, how many Seattle jobs would be correct to see in Romania today, 77 or 5?

Comment: @bosonix there are 5 jobs visible from Romania. 75 jobs in total that can be seen from the US. stackoverflow.com/jobs is a smart proxy to careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs so no difference there...

Comment: @bosonix updated the post. stackoverflow.com/jobs and careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs *did* have differences while that bug was present. That would explain the inconsistent results you're seeing... But not why we don't see your requests in the logs...

Comment: I tried the search again it it seems to be working fine now; it is showing me just 7 results for Seattle.

Comment: @bosonix well, that is strange. I'm still somewhat confused *why* your requests were not showing up in the logs on our end, I'll continue looking into that. Sorry for all the hassle :/

Comment: Do you see the recent requests from my IP in the logs now? I did many of them in the last 30-45 minutes, some logged in some not.

Comment: @bosonix looks like when things come via so.com/jobs strange (but not unexpected) things happen in the logs. I'm fixing that now!