# Inconsistent Results Between "Jobs" and "Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Similar to the previously asked question regarding  the [Difference between the two job feeds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312937/difference-between-the-two-job-feeds).

When searching Careers for [C# Jobs in Calgary](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=C%23&type=&location=Calgary&range=20&distanceUnits=Km), several results are returned that were posted one to four weeks ago; the [same search using Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=C%23&location=Calgary&range=20&distanceUnits=Miles) yields no results. I regularly watch the Careers box shown below for new/interesting postings; however when you click on either of the `Jobs near you` or `More jobs near Calgary...` links, you are also taken to a page with no or very different results.

[image]

The individual job links do take you to the expected position details, although those pages do not highlight when the posting was added (i.e., one day ago or 4 weeks ago) so I tend to prefer the search result screen.

Should the postings on Careers and Jobs be in sync at this point? Is Careers still considered the definitive list of current postings in an area?

Comment: Thanks for the report Chris. We've had a similar report for Tehran. I'm looking into it, something strange afoot.

Comment: I can't reproduce this... If I pretend to be your IP in Chrome incognito I see 3 results for 'Calgary' and C#. Can you provide more information? Careers and Jobs on SO run exactly the same underlying code.

Comment: I am on a different machine today and see the same results... when I access the first link `C# Jobs in Calgary` 3 results are returned, the second link `same search using Jobs` returns zero results. For kicks, I tried FireFox and Edge in addition to chrome... I also tried the links without being signed in and always see the same behavior. What additional information would be helpful?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm looking. I'm verifying that we're actually getting the right geo coding data right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is embarrassing... When testing for these kinds of issues we effectively impersonate your IP address and check all the routes that could be affected by this.

Unfortunately the bug for this was in a code path that was never hit when we impersonate. I'm getting our support team (and devs!) to use a VPN to the relevant location in future which makes reproducing such issues less likely to fail.

Thanks for the report, build has been pushed to production now.

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the quick turnaround!